# Update fields dynamically via jQuery slider/Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, uislider

I'm attempting to use [this](https://gist.github.com/karthikshiraly/1593688) Backbone.js demo to dynamically update fields according to the slider position. However, when the `updateVal` handler is called it doesn't seem to recognize the `.slider` attribute of the DOM element. First time using Backbone/js MVC framework so any/all words of wisdom are welcome.

Here's a screen shot of the error

[image]

**Backbone app**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initialize jquery slider
    $("#slider").slider();

    // Create the model class via Backbone (which sets up things like prototype objects correctly). 
    // This particular model is a very simple one. It'll have just 1 attribute - "slidervalue"
    var SliderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    // A "View" abstraction for the slider.
    // Whenever the slider position changes, this view updates the model with the new value.
    var SliderView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#slider"), // Specifies the DOM element which this view handles

        events: {
            // Call the event handler "updateVal" when slider value changes.
            // 'slidechange' is the jquery slider widget's event type. 
            // Refer http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default for information about 'slidechange'.
            "slidestart": "updateVal",
            "slidestop" : "updateVal"
        },

        updateVal: function () {
            // Get slider value and set it in model using model's 'set' method.
            console.log('SliderView.updateVal');
            var val = this.el.slider("option", "value");
            this.model.set({ slidervalue: val });
        }
    });

    // The listener "View" for the model.
    // Whenever the model's slidervalue attribute changes, this view receives the updated value.
    var ValueView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (args) {
            // _.bindAll is provided by underscore.js. 
            // Due to some javascript quirks, event handlers which are bound receive a 'this' 
            // value which is "useless" (according to underscore's docs).
            // _.bindAll is a hack that ensures that 'this' in event handler refers to this view.
            _.bindAll(this, 'updateValue');


            console.log('ValueView.initialize');

            // Bind an event handler to receive updates from the model whenever its
            // 'slidervalue' attribute changes.
            this.model.bind('change:slidervalue', this.updateValue);
            console.log(this);
        },

        updateValue: function () {

            // Get the slider value from model, and display it in textbox.
            console.log('ValueView.updateValue');

            // this.model won't work unless "_.bindAll(this, ...)" has been called in initialize
            var value = this.model.get('slidervalue');
            console.log(value);
            $("#sliderVal").val(value);
        }
    });

    // Create the instances
    var sliderModel = new SliderModel;
    var sliderView = new SliderView({ model: sliderModel });
    var valView = new ValueView({ model: sliderModel });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <!-- "slider" is a jquery slider -->
    <div id="slider"></div>

    <!-- "sliderVal" displays the slider's position. It receives the value via model. -->
    <input type="text" id="sliderVal" value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 var val = this.$el.slider("option", "value");
```

View.el is the actual DOM object, View.$el is wrapped in a jquery object.

Comment: If I loaded a larger section of the DOM that included the jquery object, and I wanted to access that particular element (in this case it would be the slider) would I still need to use the `$` and if so would it be on the `el` or the slider? (or does it even work like that?)

Comment: If the view is attached to an ancestor DOM object, $el would refer to that object. You'd could access the slider like $el.<path.to.slider>.slider().